# Want to convert a csv file column into an array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, csv

I am totally new to this part . I have a `CSV` file which contains different columns. From that one column has more than one values.So, My main aim is that I want to use that CSV data in MongoDB. So, I have imported the data as well from CSV to MongoDB . But It contains one array , so while importing that it is treating that as a string not as an array . So, How can I solve this problem ?
My JSON should be like,

```
 {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58456d9b16784d2b36ea67ec"),
                "names" : [abc,pqr],
                "url" : "abc.com",
                "noticePeriod" : 56,
                "payScale" : "H"
        },
```

So, here is array names .

so after using CSV ,

```
 {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("58456d9b16784d2b36ea67ec"),
                    "names" : "abc,pqr",
                    "url" : "abc.com",
                    "noticePeriod" : 56,
                    "payScale" : "H"
            },
```

Comment: the 2nd json is what you have and 1st is what you want?

Comment: after importing from CSV I am getting 2nd JSON , But my requirement is 1st JSON.

Comment: i never worked with json but i'd suggest you take the string from your 2nd json and create an array from it and then replace the string with the array

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well, But it is giving me a JSON like                                   {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("58456d9b16784d2b36ea67ec"),
                    "names" : ["abc,pqr"],
                    "url" : "abc.com",
                    "noticePeriod" : 56,
                    "payScale" : "H"
            },

Comment: like the 2nd one?

Comment: Want to have like 1st JSON.

Comment: you can only gt the 1st one if they are numbers. strings are always displayed with `""`. there is no way i know to change that

Answer (score 0):

Actually , you can solve this problem by

First Import the `csv` file in MongoDB.

```
mongoimport -d NameofDB -c NameOfCollection --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline
```

And then you can use

```
db.Collection_Name.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {   el.WantToConvertArray= el.WantToConvertArray.split(',');   db.companies.save(el); });
```

Solved my problem.